# Why is my service timing out when I can clearly see it started properly?

Tags: systemd, services, nodejs

Here is my log :

```
Feb 10 10:19:25 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Starting TNR Photo Download Service...
Feb 10 10:19:26 ip-172-31-47-29 tnr-photos[67938]: Server running on port 2200
Feb 10 10:20:56 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 10 10:20:56 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 10 10:20:56 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Failed to start TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:21:01 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 14.
Feb 10 10:21:01 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Stopped TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:21:01 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Starting TNR Photo Download Service...
Feb 10 10:21:01 ip-172-31-47-29 tnr-photos[67988]: Server running on port 2200
Feb 10 10:22:31 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 10 10:22:31 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 10 10:22:31 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Failed to start TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:22:36 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 15.
Feb 10 10:22:36 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Stopped TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:22:36 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Starting TNR Photo Download Service...
Feb 10 10:22:37 ip-172-31-47-29 tnr-photos[68036]: Server running on port 2200
Feb 10 10:24:07 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 10 10:24:07 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 10 10:24:07 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Failed to start TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:24:12 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 16.
Feb 10 10:24:12 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Stopped TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:24:12 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Starting TNR Photo Download Service...
Feb 10 10:24:12 ip-172-31-47-29 tnr-photos[68068]: Server running on port 2200
Feb 10 10:25:42 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Feb 10 10:25:42 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Feb 10 10:25:42 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Failed to start TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:25:47 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: tnr-photos.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 17.
Feb 10 10:25:47 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Stopped TNR Photo Download Service.
Feb 10 10:25:47 ip-172-31-47-29 systemd[1]: Starting TNR Photo Download Service...
Feb 10 10:25:48 ip-172-31-47-29 tnr-photos[68101]: Server running on port 2200
```

The service is defined as follows :

```
[Unit]
Description=TNR Photo Download Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=tnr-photos
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/tnr-web-photos
ExecStart=sudo /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/tnr-web-photos/index.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It's a very simple `nodeJS` server and all the lines `tnr-photos[68101]: Server running on port 2200` indicate that it is in fact starting properly.

How come it keeps timing out ?

Comment: Does this still happen, when you change `Type=forking` to `Type=simple`?

Comment: I will try and report back.

Comment: that was it thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the solution in my comment: Some applications don't use the `fork()` systemcall as expected (or not at all), which can confuse `systemd` when `Type=forking` is set. Usually, this can be avoided by setting `Type=simple`.